# ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long in Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have this query running in a Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production, PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production, CORE   11.2.0.4.0  Production, TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production, NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "IOT"."V_USERS_AND_RIGHTS" ("USER_PRIMARY_UNIT", "LOGIN", "FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME", "UNIT_ROLE") AS 
  SELECT "USER_PRIMARY_UNIT","LOGIN","FIRST_NAME","LAST_NAME","UNIT_ROLE"
FROM (
SELECT user_primary_unit,login, first_name,  last_name,
       LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(rights,' / '))
       KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),' / ') AS UNIT_ROLE
      FROM  
        (SELECT  login,
              first_name,  
              last_name,
              user_primary_unit,
              rights,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY login ORDER BY rights) AS curr,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY login ORDER BY rights) -1 AS prev
        FROM  (select   member0_.login,  member0_.first_name first_name, unit2.unit_name user_primary_unit,  member0_.last_name last_name,
                        CONCAT(CONCAT(unit.unit_name, ' - '), role3_.role_name) rights 
 from
  IOT_DEVICES.t_member member0_
 inner join  IOT_DEVICES.t_user member0_1_    on member0_.member_id=member0_1_.user_id
 inner join  IOT_DEVICES.t_playable_role playedrole1_    on member0_.member_id=playedrole1_.user_id
 inner join  IOT_DEVICES.t_unit_role unitrole2_    on playedrole1_.unit_role_id=unitrole2_.unit_role_id
 inner join  IOT_DEVICES.t_role role3_    on unitrole2_.role_id=role3_.role_id
 inner join  IOT_DEVICES.t_unit unit    on unitrole2_.unit_id=unit.unit_id
 inner join  IOT_DEVICES.t_unit unit2    on unit2.unit_id=member0_1_.primary_unit_id
 where    current_date between playedrole1_.start_date and playedrole1_.end_date
 order by unit.unit_name
  ))
GROUP BY login, first_name,  last_name, user_primary_unit
CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND login = PRIOR login
START WITH curr = 1
)
ORDER BY user_PRIMARY_UNIT, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME;
```

but I have this error :

```
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"
*Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
*Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.
```

even I set all these variables:

```
SET LONG 2000000
SET pagesize 50000
set longchunk 1000
set linesize 1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not related to sqlplus settings but rather to the varchar2 size limit in SQL engine in Oracle DB. For 11g the limit is 4000 bytes.

While processing your query, one of concatenations result in the string with length greater than the limit.

At first glance the combination of

```
... LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(rights,' / ')) ...
```

and

```
... CONCAT(CONCAT(unit.unit_name, ' - '), role3_.role_name) rights ...
```

might cause the issue. Either you have lots of rights for a unit, or you have a deep hierarchy.